# Checked list with entity framework Code first

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have two objects ListingActivity and Activity, ListingActivities is used to link activities to Listings.

Here is the objects

```
public class ListingActivity
{
    [Key]
    public int ListingActivityId { get; set; }
    public Activity Activity { get; set; }
    public Listing Listing { get; set; }
}

public class Activity
{
    [Key]
    public int ActivityId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ListingActivity ListingActivity { get; set; }
}
```

I want to have a checklist so that the user can see what activities is already linked to the listing and then the option to select the ones that are not linked. I know how to do the UI and everything. But how will this query look like using Code First Entity Framework.

I have implemented similar functionality with SQL then it looks more or less like this (Disclaimer : PSEUDO SQL)

```
select case when ListingActivity!=null then 'checked' else 'not checked'
from Activity
left join ListingActivity
```

Comment: Is `Activity-ListingActivity` 1:n?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I wanted, posting it here, it might help someone in the future

```
var actList = (from a in db.Activities
                           join la in db.ListingActivities on a.ActivityId equals la.Activity.ActivityId into
                               tempActivities
                           from listingActivites in tempActivities.DefaultIfEmpty()
                           select new ListingActivityItem()
                                      {
                                          ListingActivityId = listingActivites.ListingActivityId,
                                          Activity = a,
                                          Checked = listingActivites.Listing != null
                                      }).OrderBy(p=>p.Activity.Name).ToList();
            return actList;
```